# Configure proxy in Apache to remove authentication

Tags: apache, authentication, reverse-proxy, confluence, confluence-rest-api

In the interest of avoiding yak-shaving, I'll try to provide as much context as possible.

We have an internal application that's also available on the public internet. This application runs on several instances of Apache on the IBM i - most of these instances require http basic authentication, except for one instance that acts as the 'welcome page' so to speak. This 'welcome page' has no authentication, but acts as a navigation hub with links for the user to go to other parts of the app (which DO have authentication and run on different instances of Apache).

We also have some documentation stored in Confluence (a wiki application) that runs on a separate server. This wiki application can display the documentation without requiring authentication, but if you authenticate, you then have the option to edit the documentation (assuming you're authorized to do so, of course). But the key is that the documentation is visible without requiring authentication.

My problem is: we want the documentation in Confluence to be accessible from within the main application (both when being accessed internally and over the internet) but, because the documentation is somewhat sensitive, we don't want it accessible to the internet at large.

The solution we came up with was to use a reverse proxy - we configure the Apache instances on the main application such that requests to `/help/` on the main application are proxied to the confluence application. Thus, the Confluence application is not directly exposed to the Internet.

**But this is where the problem starts.**

If we just proxy `/help/` through the main application Apache instance that doesn't require authentication, then the documentation is available from the main application without a problem - but since you don't require authentication, it's available to everyone on the Internet as well - so that's a no-go.

if we instead proxy '/help/' through the main application Apache instances that DO require authentication, it seems as though the basic authentication information is passed from the main application servers onto the Confluence server, and then we get an authentication failure, because not everyone who uses the main application has an account on the Confluence server. (For those that do, it works fine - but the majority of users won't have a Confluence account).

***(Possible yak shaving alert from this point forward)***

So, it seems as though when dealing with HTTP Basic authentication, if you set up proxy configuration from server A to server B, and set up the proxy on server A to require http basic authentication, then that authentication information is passed straight through to the server B, and in this scenario, server B complains since it doesn't expect authentication information.

My solution to that problem was to set up 2 levels of proxying - use the Apache instances requiring authentication to also require authentication for the proxy to `/help/`, but have `/help/` proxy to a different server (Server C). This Server C doesn't require authentication but is not exposed to the internet. And Server C is configured to proxy `/help/` to the actual Confluence server.

I did this on the basis of `proxy-chain-auth` - an environment variable which seems to indicate that by default, if you have a proxy chain, the authentication information is NOT automatically sent along the chain.

Alas, this did not work - i got an authentication error that seems to indicate that Server C did in fact proxy the authentication info onwards, even though i did not set `proxy-chain-auth`.

So, that's my yak-shaving journey.

I simply want to set up a configuration such that our documentation stored on Confluence requires some sort of authentication, but that authentication comes from the main application, not from Confluence.

*(Without the requirement of having it accessible over the internet, none of this would've been an issue since the Confluence server can be viewed by anyone on its network without a problem).*

I hope my question is clear enough - I honestly don't mind being pointed in a different direction to achieve the main goal, with the caveat that I can't change the main application (or Confluence for that matter) from using HTTP Basic Authentication.

Ideas, anyone?

PS. To retrieve the documentation from the Confluence server, I'm actually using their REST API to retrieve the page content - i don't know if that has any relevance, but I just wanted that made clear in case it does.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the solution to the issue was pretty straightforward.

For my second proxy that does not require authentication, I had to change the Apache configuration to remove any authorization headers.

```
RequestHeader unset Authorization
```

This stops the authentication information from being passed from the second proxy onto Confluence.